# How to add a suffix (like measure units cm, m, km, etc) at the end of a float in my list?

Tags: python, arrays, list, suffix

I have to make a program that will allow the user to save people's personal information like their last names, first names, genders, heights and so on... I am not allowed to use dictionaries so no use in recommending it.

I don't know how to add the suffix "cm" when I print the person's height. Here is my code that request height input:

starting line 68

```
taille = input("Entrez la taille de la personne en cm (0 à 250) :\n").strip()
isTailleValid = validation_taille(taille)
while not isTailleValid:
    taille = input("Taille invalide, entrez bien une valeur entre 0 et 250 :\n").strip()
    isTailleValid = validation_taille(taille)
    taille = float(taille)
personInf[Personne_taille] = taille
```

This is where the program request information about the height (french: taille) after that it adds that input to a list called Liste_info under the Personne_taille index by doing:

```
Liste_info.append(personInf)
```

now when I call the function to print out the result it shows up like this:

[image]

Is there any way to add " cm" at the end of 175?

Comment: `isTailleValid` ça pique les yeux :'(

Comment: personInf[Personne_taille] = (taille)+" cm"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while not isTailleValid:
    taille = input("Taille invalide, entrez bien une valeur entre 0 et 250 :\n").strip()
    isTailleValid = validation_taille(taille)
personInf[Personne_taille] = taille + "cm"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to make the float a `str` type then merge the strings

```
while not isTailleValid:
    taille = input("Taille invalide, entrez bien une valeur entre 0 et 250 :\n").strip()
    isTailleValid = validation_taille(taille)
personInf[Personne_taille] = str(taille) + " cm"
```

Comment: Is it possible for me to revert that back to float later on? Because one of the options for the program is to calculate the average height of every single person saved.

Comment: I think you should store the height as a float in `personInf`, and when you display it, simply add "cm" after the value.

Comment: @Bao Tang actually did have you floats at all? If `taille + " cm"` works then both are string type

Comment: yes, you can simply do `float("175")` to convert it to float, `float("175 cm")` does *not* work because it cannot be converted to float type

Comment: it is possible to create your own python data type aware of units, for example https://pint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/